# Failure to send message

Tags: c#, smtp

This is the code I have tried:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Web;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication6
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



                MailMessage reece = new MailMessage("FromEmail", "ToEmail", "Hello", "How are you");
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
         smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("MyEmail", "MyPassword");
                smtp.Port = 465;

                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(reece);
                MessageBox.Show("Sent");
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting timed out. Tried so much different combinations of ports too.

Answer (score 1):

The server you are trying to connect requires SSL enabled.

```
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
```

Also change port to `995` or `465`.

More here: https://portal.smartertools.com/kb/a2862/smtp-settings-for-outlook365-and-gmail.aspx

Comment: Added that, same problem.

Comment: Then check if `password` and `username` are correct. Also, check my updated answer.

Comment: check for your antivirus settings.

Comment: @Reece see my updated answer. Office365 use 995 as SSL port.